# Errors in high-level relational engine. Transaction aborted when processing dimension

Tags: ssas, teradata

I'm trying to process a dimension and keep getting a "Error in high-level relational engine" error, and the DB returns that transaction was aborted by user (the user being SSAS in this case).  This is using a Teradata database.

This is not a very descriptive error message and am unsure how to troubleshoot this.

When I copy the SQL that SSAS generates and run it separately it works fine.

Has anyone encountered this and have any suggestions for where the error could be?

[image]

Comment: Going to need more details about the scenario. The 3110 error could be related to a command timeout setting in the Teradata client that is aborting any statement that doesn’t complete in the allotted time. The 3110 error indicates the client initiated the abort of the query. Which driver are you using (ODBC, .Net, JDBC)? What version of the client? What version of the database? How long does the statement execute on its own outside of SSAS?

Comment: @RobPaller  It turned out that there was another error that was aborting all the other queries.  A duplicate key error.  So I'm going down that path to figure out how to fix that.